# Defining Laravel relationships at runtime

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I am trying to build a headless CMS package similar to Strapi.

I have a model called `Resource`, which is a catch-all model for any models added via my package UI.

I am struggling with defining relationships at runtime.

Let's say I have a database with these tables:

```
Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->integer('brand_id');
    $table->string('name');
});
```

I've seeded a bunch of records into these tables, so I know they definitely exist.

Now, as I mentioned, I have a model called `Resource` which will be used to represent either of these tables.

Here is my code, which isn't working, to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$brand = new Resource;
$brand->setTable('brands');

$vehicle = new Resource;
$vehicle->setTable('vehicles');
$vehicle->setRelation('brand', new BelongsTo($brand->newQuery(), $vehicle, 'brand_id', 'id', 'brand'));

$vehicles = $vehicle->with('brand')->get();

dd($vehicles->toArray());
```

The `dd` is just returning an empty array every time without any errors.

How do I dynamically declare relationships at runtime using dynamically defined model tables?

Comment: Why not have separate models for both of them? They seem different to me, so why have a single model when you have two tables?

Comment: Because the models, as I mentioned, are created via a user interface. They only exist as database records with references to other database records. There is no issue with creating the `Resource` instance and setting the table. That part works. The part that I can't figure out is how to dynamically define the relationships created via the UI.

Comment: try dd($vehicles), and check the database to see if you have vehicle entries in vehicles table.

Comment: Doing `dd($vehicles)` just gives me an empty `items` array. The `with('brand')` call is causing it to be empty.

Comment: you haven't saved any of the models, You need to do ```$brand->save();``` and ```$vehicle->save();``` before you can get them from db which you do by calling ```$vehicle->with('brand')->get()```.
Also regarding setting relationship in the run time, why not just set the foreign key and save ```$vehicle->brand_id = $brand->id``` after saving brand surely.
if this doesn't solve the issue please share the Resource model code for us to get a better idea